# Serialize class types in XML

Tags: xml, serialization

I am working on an app where the user is able to define jobs with tasks. The user can execute this jobs and the tasks are executed.

Tasks are classes which are derived from a base class. My idea was to let other programmers implement their own tasks which can be executed.
As I want to save the job definitions to an xml file, I also have to serialize the tasks. I thought of something like this:

```
<Task TypeName="SaveFile">...</Task>
```

The "TypeName" attribute describes the type of the task.

I wouldn't have any problems, if I was the only one who implements tasks. I could easily give them unique names. But if later (hopefully) a lot of custom tasks are implemented, how can I ensure that there are no name collissions?

Comment: You do this by using the TypeName already?

Comment: No, currently I am just planning. It was just an idea to do it like described above